# can each import create a separate object?

Tags: python, python-import

Imagine a library of classes supporting different input or output formats. Applications may switch between those formats. I'm using different languages only as an example.

A straightforward way to set the format could look like this:

```
import mytimes

mytimes.set_input_format("German")
mytimes.Days("1.Mai", "31.Dezember")
mytimes.set_input_format("ISO8601")
mytimes.Date("2023-11-02")
```

Global state is not good. If the `import`-s are not grouped the usual way, it could fail:

```
import mytimes
mytimes.set_input_format("German")
from . import foo       # happens to contain mytimes.set_input_format("English")
mytimes.func("1.Juni")  # not valid in English
```

That's why this is better:

```
from mytimes_v2 import MyTimes

mytimes = MyTimes()
mytimes.set_input_format("German")
```

Could that be somehow automated? Could a module simply do `from mytimes_v3 import mytimes` and get its own instance that could be configured independently from instances imported elsewhere?

Comment: No. There's only one instance of the module, which contains all its global state, no matter how many times it's imported or which type of import syntax is used.

Comment: The first rule should be to not have unorthodox magic behavior. Have you ever seen a library that works as you describe, and wouldn’t you be surprised by it? Why not simply `mytimes = MyTimes('German')`?

Comment: As you suggested, this is poor design for the library, it makes it difficult for it to be used independently by multiple parts of the importing code.

Comment: The normal import mechanism doesn't support that - everyone importing the same name from the module gets exactly the same module.  However, modules can apparently replace their entry in `sys.modules` with a custom object that behaves differently (I've never done this myself, so am not clear on the details).  If this object had `mytimes` as a property, rather than an attribute as usual, it could return a distinct instance to each caller.

Comment: The goal here was to *reduce* bugs (by eliminating global state). This would increase bugs. For example, any code that tried to do `import mytimes_v3` and then use `mytimes_v3.mytimes` would probably break, generating a new format context thing on every access. Just leave the format context creation explicit.

Comment: All your comments are good and valid points in general. OTOH this library is used to describe something static with a series of declarations. An analogy of the format used in those declarations could be setting the font type or size on a document. It should not interfere with font in other documents even if they belong together. I think I have to think it over again. How to combine the  "Least astonishment" and "Practicality beats purity" etc.  Thanks for the feedback.